# Input Text in Checkbox to JSON data

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, json, dom

I want to store checkbox data as JSON to .txt file.
The last checkbox is text type input for "other" options, but when I submit with that "other" value it gives only that "other" value as the only checked data, ignoring the rest checked.

```html
<div id="form22" class="form-group checkbox-type">
                <div class="form-section-heading">
                    <label class="heading">Project's business model <span class="required">*</span></label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="form22_check1" value="B2B" name="Project's business model">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="form22_check">
                        B2B
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="form22_check2" value="B2C" name="Project's business model">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="form22_check2">
                        B2C
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="form22_checkn" name="Project's business model">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="form22_checkn">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputBModel" placeholder="Other" name="Project's business model">
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

Here is my code to store checkbox data as JSON object:

```
     const reducerFunction = (data, element) => {
    data[element.name] = element.value;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    return data;
};

const isValidValue = element => {
    return (!['checkbox', 'radio'].includes(element.type) || element.checked);
};

const isValidElement = element => {
    return element.name && element.value;
};

const isCheckbox = element => element.type === 'checkbox';
const isMultiSelect = element => element.options && element.multiple;

const formToJSON = elements => [].reduce.call(elements, (data, element) => {

    if (isValidElement(element) && isValidValue(element)) {
        if (isCheckbox(element)) {
            data[element.name] = (data[element.name] || []).concat(element.value);
        } else {
            data[element.name] = element.value;
        }
    } else {
        data[element.name] = (data[element.name] || null);
    }

    return data;
}, {});

const handleFormSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const data = formToJSON(form.elements);
    const readyData = JSON.stringify(data, null, "  ");
    console.log(readyData);
```

Expected output:

```
"Project's business model": [
   "B2C",
   "test"
],
```

The output I get:

```
 "Project's business model": "test"
```

Comment: Did you check whether `isCheckbox(element)` is returning true ?

Comment: @mangesh yes, for everything else it works correctly

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you provide more code. How are you iterating over all the elements ? What is the implementation in `isCheckbox` ?

Comment: @mangesh I've edited my post, now you can see the whole code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the checkbox for 'Other' does not have any value. The input field of type text is the one giving the value "test". You can write a *oninput* event handler for the text field that updates the value of the corresponding checkbox. Also make sure name of text input field is different than checkbox name.

```
            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="form22_checkn" name="Project's business model">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="form22_checkn">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputBModel" placeholder="Other" name="Project's business model user input" oninput="updateCheckboxValue()">
                </label>
            </div>
           <script>function updateCheckboxValue(){document.getElementById("form22_checkn").value = document.getElementById("inputBModel").value;}</script>
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null :( it did not work

Comment: I think we have to add something to the If(isCheckbox) but still couldn't figure out what exactly

Comment: Can you try putting `<script>function updateCheckboxValue(){
    document.getElementById("form22_checkn").value = document.getElementById("inputBModel").value;
  }</script>` in the html file ?

Comment: I think `isCheckbox` is fine, but the problem is "test" value is coming from text field rather than checkbox field.

Comment: still the same thing

Comment: Actually your way of solving the problem was correct! I just had some other issues as well.. that's why it didn't make sense at first. Thank you!